# pyodbc.dataSources() returning empty dict

Tags: python-2.7, pyodbc

I have installed an ODBC driver in my machine and created a user DSN

[image]

But when i am trying to print data sources in Python it is returning an empty dict:

```
    import pyodbc
    print pyodbc.dataSources()
    output: {}
```

How can I list my DSN in code and work with it?

Comment: What `pyodbc.version` are you using? I just tried your code with pyodbc 4.0.21 on Windows_7 64-bit and it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Also, verify that you are running 64-bit Python (if you want to see 64-bit DSNs).

Comment: Thanks a lot ... !! the reason for not listing drivers is because of using 32 bit python